# Taking a screenshot of a body containg different iframe, embed, webview

Tags: javascript, html, electron, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I have a particular problem when using any library to take a screenshot for my webpage containing videos (with embed html tags) and webpages (with iframe and webview in electron).

I tried "html2canvas" (even with allowTaint: true) and "domtoimage" but the content of these html object remain empty in the screenshot taken.

Do you have any idea on how to fix that ?